# Check if a .txt file exists. FileWriter.exists method not working

Tags: java, filewriter

SOLVED!!! Thanks for the hand guys got it working. Appreciate it!

I'm writing a program that has user name and password input. I am trying to check if a file exists for a user if the user puts in a user name that already exists when they create a user name and password.

The .exists method isn't working and I cant figure it out. Error cannot find symbol comes back. I've changed things, moved things around and got it down to one error. Tried using loops as well as if statements but using if gets me to only one error .Any help would be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class UserData 
{
  public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
  {
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Do you have an account? Yes or No: ");
  String answer = kb.next().trim();

  if ((answer.startsWith("N")) || (answer.startsWith("n")))
  {

System.out.println("Create user name: ");
String user = kb.next().trim();

String fileName = user + ".txt";
FileWriter userData = new FileWriter(fileName);

 if (userData.exists())
 {
   System.out.println("User already exists");
   System.out.println("Create user name: ");
   user = kb.next().trim();

   fileName = user + ".txt";
   userData = new FileWriter(fileName);
 }

System.out.println("Create Password: ");
String ps = kb.next().trim();

userData.write(user + " ");
userData.write(ps);
userData.close();


  }

  else if ((answer.startsWith("Y")) || (answer.startsWith("y")))
  {
System.out.println("Enter user name: ");
String user = kb.next().trim();

System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
String ps = kb.next().trim();

String fileName = user + ".txt";
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

String userName = inFile.next();
String password = inFile.next();

//     If ((userName != user) || (password != ps))
//     {
//       System.out.println("User Not Found");
//       System.out.println("Enter user name: ");
//       String user = kb.next().trim();
// 
//       System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
//       String ps = kb.next().trim();
//  
//       String fileName = user + ".txt";
//       Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
//  
//       String userName = inFile.next();
//       String password = inFile.next();
//     }
//     else
//     {
   System.out.println("User Found");
//     }
}





}}
```

Comment: try to open the file, using try-catch and if the exception is caught then the file doesn't exist else it exists

Comment: Not seen `exists()` method in [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) !!!!

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. Working great now. Very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have compilation error here:

```
FileWriter userData = new FileWriter(fileName);
if (userData.exists())
```

Change it to:

```
File userDataFile = new File(fileName);
if (userDataFile.exists())
```

and of course:

```
FileWriter userData = new FileWriter(userDataFile);
userData.write(user + " ");
userData.write(ps);
userData.close();
```

If file doesn't exist anyway, you might be looking in a wrong directory. Try to add this:

```
System.out.println(new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath());
```

And check yourself if the file available on the printed path.

Comment: Thanks for that. Working fine now. Appreciate it.